# Labelling in between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

Basically I have the code below and it draws me nodes and I just want to put the label delta x between and above nodes 1 and 2 and delta y in between and to the left nodes 1 and 5. How do I do it?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
    \tikzstyle{every node} = [circle, fill=black!30]


\node [label={ $\Delta x $}] (a)  {1};
\node(b)             [right=of a] {2};
\node(c)             [right=of b] {3};
\node(d)             [right=of c] {4};
\node [label={ $\Delta y $}] (e) [below= of a] {5};
\node(f)             [right=of e] {6};
\node(g)             [right =of f] {7};
\node(h)             [right= of g] {8};


\foreach \from/\to in {a/b, a/e}
\draw [-] (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    % load library to position nodes relatively to each other
    \usetikzlibrary{
        positioning,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % use a scope to state the style of the (main) nodes
        \begin{scope}[
            every node/.append style={
                circle,
                fill=black!30,
            },
        ]
            \node (a)              {1};
            \node (b) [right=of a] {2};
            \node (c) [right=of b] {3};
            \node (d) [right=of c] {4};
            \node (e) [below=of a] {5};
            \node (f) [right=of e] {6};
            \node (g) [right=of f] {7};
            \node (h) [right=of g] {8};
        \end{scope}

        % then you can draw the lines between the nodes you want to
        % connect and place nodes on that path
        % (because this nodes are outside of the scope,
        %  they are drawn with the default style)
        \draw  (a) -- node [above] {$\Delta x$} (b);
        \draw  (a) -- node [left]  {$\Delta y$} (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]